# Error while pip installing scipy 0.19.1 : "don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform"?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip

I get a very large error log when i am trying to install scipy 0.19.1 (it is needed by a project i am trying to run) and I'm actually not sure which part is the main error because there seem to be many errors happening:

```
C:\Users\John>pip install scipy==0.19.1
Collecting scipy==0.19.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/67/d9ef9b5058d4a9e3f0ae641ec151790622cbeb37f157de5773358e2bf3da/scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable DF
    Could not locate executable efl
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    Could not locate executable g95
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    Running from numpy source directory.
    C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\setup.py:480: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 157, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 248, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 278, in run
        return func()
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 246, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\setup.py", line 508, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\setup.py", line 500, in setup_package
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 152, in run
        self.run_command("egg_info")
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 24, in run
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 144, in run
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 155, in build_sources
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 288, in build_library_sources
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
      File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 663, in get_mathlib_info
    RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9ky_jp3j\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9ky_jp3j\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 315, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 850, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1122, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1134, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 665, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 695, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 876, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1115, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1101, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 251, in run_setup
        raise
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 169, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 144, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 157, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 248, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 278, in run
        return func()
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 246, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\setup.py", line 508, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\setup.py", line 500, in setup_package
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 152, in run
        self.run_command("egg_info")
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 24, in run
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 144, in run
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 155, in build_sources
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 288, in build_library_sources
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-wq9y_09v\numpy-1.19.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
      File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 663, in get_mathlib_info
    RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
    Generating code
    Finished generating code
    LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9ky_jp3j\scipy\
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

at first it was giving me errors about not finding Cython, so i installed it, not this is happening, how can i solve it?

my python version is 3.6.1, and pip version is 8.1.1, both of which is needed by the project so i don't think i can change them.

Comment: You have a very old `pip` version. You should first run `python -m pip install -U pip` and then try to install scipy 0.19.1 again `pip install scipy==0.19.1`

Comment: @TirthPatel but for some reason the repository says the pip needs to be 8.1.1, is there any other way other than upgrading pip?

Comment: I don't know why would a project restrict to such an old pip version. I am not sure if I have any other solution right now. But pip is very backward compatible and you should be good with newer pip versions.

Comment: Imho, the core problem is, that there are no pre-built binaries for such an outdated version, which means, that you need to compile from sources, which won't work on windows (it's very hard; there is a reason scipy had no official binaries for many years). I really really recommend reflecting about the `scipy==0.19.1` dependency and in the worst-case, rather port the code instead of using such an old version. If that's a do-once thing, consider going for linux where it's much easier to compile from sources. See the non-existence of windows [here](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/0.19.1/#files).